# Firing multiple events onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I believe in this case I'm simply lacking knowledge on some point. I am trying to simulate a few different event types when a user clicks into an input field. I am using jquery to accomplish this. However, at the moment I'm getting a generic "undefined" error.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="test" type="text" name="test" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').click(function () {
        $('#test').keydown();
        $('#test').focus();
        $('#test').change();
    });
});

$(function () {
    ('#test').on('keydown', function(){  
        $('<p>test!</p>').insertAfter('#test');
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the code I'm attempting to use.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/P55Xw/1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed `$` sign in your selector! And I think you didn't included jquery in fiddle.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P55Xw/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').click(function () {
        $('#test').keydown();
        $('#test').focus();
        $('#test').change();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#test').on('keydown', function(){  //Here you missed the $ sign for selector
        $('<p>test!</p>').insertAfter('#test');
    });
});
```